# Golang - Gmail API 400 BadRequest Failed Precondition

Tags: go, google-api, gmail-api

I've been struggling against this error (`googleapi: Error 400: Bad Request, failedPrecondition`) for about 8 hours now. I've written a simple go program which reproduces the problem for me. Maybe someone familiar with the Google APIs can help me out.

The error is the same as the one mentioned here: [Gmail REST API : 400 Bad Request + Failed Precondition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327846/gmail-rest-api-400-bad-request-failed-precondition). The only difference is that it is in Go. I've followed the steps but still no luck.

I've also updated my code based on [How to send email through Gmail Go SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382821/how-to-send-email-through-gmail-go-sdk/25387678#25387678)

Both questions were helpful but did not help resolve the latest issue. I have also set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to my project's json.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/mail"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"

    gmail "google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1"
)

func main() {
    // Use oauth2.NoContext if there isn't a good context to pass in.
    ctx := context.TODO()

    client, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, gmail.GmailSendScope)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // create service
    svc, err := gmail.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to create Gmail service: %v", err)
    }

    if err := SendEmail(ctx, svc, <redacted>); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to send email: %v", err)
    }
}

func SendEmail(ctx context.Context, svc *gmail.Service, email string) error {
    from := mail.Address{"", "noreply@example.com"}

    header := make(map[string]string)
    header["From"] = from.String()
    header["To"] = email
    header["Subject"] = encodeRFC2047("Hello, Gmail!")
    header["MIME-Version"] = "1.0"
    header["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\""
    header["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "base64"

    var msg string
    for k, v := range header {
        msg += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
    }
    msg += "\r\n" + "Hello, Gmail!"

    gmsg := gmail.Message{
        Raw: encodeWeb64String([]byte(msg)),
    }

    _, err := svc.Users.Messages.Send("me", &gmsg).Do()
    return err
}

func encodeRFC2047(s string) string {
    // use mail's rfc2047 to encode any string
    addr := mail.Address{s, ""}
    return strings.Trim(addr.String(), " <>")
}

func encodeWeb64String(b []byte) string {

    s := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b)

    var i = len(s) - 1
    for s[i] == '=' {
        i--
    }

    return s[0 : i+1]
}
```

Running the code above should produce the following error:

```
2015/12/12 22:16:46 failed to send email: googleapi: Error 400: Bad Request, failedPrecondition
```

Comment: It looks like there is something malformed in your request. Can you provide the full request?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any update? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To send mail, you must specify a valid address for the From: header (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).  `noreply@example.com` is unlikely to be such an address given that example.com is a test-only domain per [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-3).